# ASP.NET page post back delay between pageloadcomplete() and onsavestatecomplete ()

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, lifecycle

I am working on a fairly complicated webpage recently, the situation is:

1. There are almost 600 server controls on this page (include tables, grid views, charts...)
2. The size of ViewState is almost 250 K.
3. For each post back (including ajax call)  -- (Server side)
   after the event handler code is done:

a. There is 1.0 ~ 1.5 s between method pageloadcomplete() and onsavestatecomplete()

b. There is 0.5 ~ 1.0 s between method onsavestatecomplete() and page_unload()

-- these delays slows down the webpage significantly.

At first I thought these delays are caused by my huge ViewState and the number of 
server controls. 
However after I disabled ViewState. The size of ViewState is now 16K, the performance is not improved as significantly as I expected.

BTW: On some simple pages in my website, these delays didn't happen.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Six hundred server controls seems like a lot, but if you still have performance issues with and without viewstate, its probably the actual code that's slowing you down. Without seeing what code is running in those events it'll be hard to provide much assistance to you.

Comment: With some adjustments you can disable ViewState completely for all controls. Once you do that the page becomes a lot faster and smaller.

Comment: Check if table controls execute read operations from db on each datarow (it should be Grid_DataBound event..): sql select launched in this event for feed each row

Comment: To Nate: I have already put log and I can tell that the actual code has already done before pageloadcomplete() is called.

Comment: To Ciro: Thanks, I will look into it and see if it helps.

Comment: To Ciro: I have two OnItemDataBound events. But there is no SQL query in that event handler, just changing the fonts. Thanks. I will comment them out and see if there is any improvement.